# How to set an activity to run in phone's background Android Studio

Tags: android, service, process, background-process

I'm trying to make an app that on options you can simply click "run in background" and the app minimizes itself and continues to run in the background. 
The problem that I'm facing is that by extending the class with "Service" some objects such as ActionBar() are displaying errors.
Please if anyone knows any code I can put under the "Run in background" button's onclickListener to make the activuty run in the phone's background please share.

Comment: make service and activity class are different then service put logic only that perform by background.

Comment: refer this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Answer (score 0):

1.Services allow you to perform various tasks while in background.[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) should help you!

2.I'm not sure about this,

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3
to
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1